# How to remove execute permission from all txt files in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, permissions, nautilus, wine, execute-command

I have a **Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit** desktop in which I had installed `wine` in the past and later removed it.  Now when I try to open **txt files** in `nautilus`, in many cases I get a *dailouge box* saying the file is **executable** and whether should I *run* or *display* it.  I am annoyed by this behaviour and want to revoke **execute** permissions from these files.  If anyone can show me how to do this it will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: do you mean files with a `.txt` extension in your home?

Comment: @Zanna Yes, all `*.txt` files across all my **partitions**.  However if a general method is shown to change permissions on a partition, I think I can do it for other partitions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove the execute bit from all `.txt` files in your home directory and all its subdirectories, try:

```
find "$HOME" -type f -executable -name '*.txt' -execdir chmod a-x {} +
```

How it works:

- `find "$HOME"`

  This starts `find` looking for files starting with your home directory and recursively including all subdirectories
- `-type f`

  This tells `find` to look only for regular files, not directories.

  It is important to restrict the search to regular files because, if we remove the execute bit from a directory, that directory become inaccessible.
- `-executable`

  This tells `find` to look only for files which have the executable bit set.
- `-name '*.txt'`

  This tells `find` to look only for files whose names match the glob `*.txt`.
- `-execdir chmod a-x {} +`

  This tells `find` to execute `chmod a-x` on any such files found.

  We use `-execdir`, as opposed to `-exec`, because it is more reliable should the names of directories change while this command is running.

  The `+` at the end of the form `-execdir chmod a-x {} +` tells `find` to run fewer instances of `chmod` by putting many files on each `chmod` command line if possible.

Comment: To be clear, I should first issue `cd /` then your command, right?

Comment: Did you want to do this to all files starting from the root directory, `/`?  Or, just your own files start files with your home directory.  If the former, then use `find / -type f -executable -name '*.txt' -execdir chmod a-x {} +`.

Comment: By the way, `find` searches for files starting with the directory specified on its command line.  If an absolute directory is specified, like `/` or `$HOME`, the the value of the current working directory is ignored and `cd` has no effect.  `cd` would only matter if a relative directory was specified.  A common example would be `find . -type f ....` which starts its search from the current working directory.

Comment: I replaced $HOME with the mounted partition paths where I have some `txt` files and used your command.

Comment: @nlern Very good.

Comment: this is not good. `-executable` is both non portable and "user centric", ie **it will miss .txt files that are executable by other users than the one running the find but not executable by the user running the find**.  Just don't add this option (so every .txt file will have their "x" dropped, even if they already don't have any...), or replace it with :   `-perm +111` (non-gnu, or old gnu find) or `-perm /111` (recent gnu find) to find files with ANY of the x set (u, g or other).

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec chmod a-x {} \;
```

`find` command is self explanatory. It finds the files according to given arguments. Usage : `find location comparison-criteria search term`

`find . -name "*.txt" -exec chmod a-x {} \;` Here . means root directory, `-name "*.txt"` means find all files which include ".txt" in their names. `-exec chmod a-x {} \;` means execute the `chmod` command on all matching files.

Comment: It would be nice if you add an explanation of your command does.

Comment: if using GNU find : replace `\;` by `+` so that it will not fork one shell chmod command for EACH file, but only when the chmod has it's parameter list filled (so it is thousands of times less called, and therefore a lot more efficient). so "`-exec chmod a-x {} \;` means execute the chmod command on all matching files"  should be "`-exec chmod a-x {} \;` means execute the chmod command on **EACH** matching file"

Comment: Would you be so kind to explain what is an 'a' in 'a-x' and how to remove results of its execution? My folder is shown in 'Administrative Root'